# Load but don't send embedded objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say you have the following model:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    owner: DS.belongsTo('App.Person', {embedded: true})
})
```

This means you can load this embedded association, but it also means that if you want to create a new Item for a person that already exists ember-data will also embed the Person object for every new item.

Is it possible to make it load embedded objects but when creating associations only send the ids? i.e send this instead:

```
{"item": {"owner_id": 5}}
```

---

**Edit:**
To clarify, I want ember-data to load embedded relations, but if I set {embedded: true}
this code:

```
App.Item.createRecord({name: 'Something', owner: App.Person.find(1)});
// And a few moments later when App.Person.find(1) has loaded
App.store.commit()
```

It will send the following json:

```
{ "item": {"name": "Something", owner: { id: 1, name: "whatever" }}
```

But what I want is:

```
{ "item": {"name": "Something", owner_id: 1 }}
```

Basically if I set embedded = true ember-data will also embed the assocations when you create an object.

Comment: What is want is exactly what happens. It does not send the embedded object. It only sends the ID. I am not sure if this feature is included in the latest version of ember-data. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version in the master branch from about a month ago. Apparently in the latest version they've removed embedded loading option and plan to include it sometime later on, see: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/428. What a mess...

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your aim, you shouldn't have to specify `{ embedded: true }`. The default ember-data behavior is to be lazy.

It you are using `active_model_serializers` *(which I strongly recommend to you)*, you should declare your server-side serializer as follow:

```ruby
class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: false
  #...
end
```

Comment: See my edit please, I want to load eagerly but it seems that enabling that option also makes ember-data send full relations instead of just their ids.

Comment: Mike's right; you need to remove `{embedded: true}`. That's what's causing ember-data to serialize the owner's attributes instead of just the id.

Regarding server-side serialization: consult the ember-data README for "sideloading;" it shows what the JSON should look like. (Or just follow Mike's recommendation of using `active_model_serializers`.)